# Is there a replacement decompile tool for jad & jadclipse on eclipse(running an 64 bit jdk)?

Tags: java, eclipse, 64-bit, decompiler

My jad can't work properly on an eclipse which running on 64 bit jdk.

Comment: i don't get your problem. do you want a decompile tool or isn't yours running properly?

Comment: What do you mean by It can't work properly, I have it on my Win 7 64bit and 64bit JDK 7, it's working perfectly.

Comment: I use Eclipse Class Decompiler. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682830/decompiling-java-class-files-without-source and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371451/jd-decompiler-for-eclipse-4-2-juno

Answer (score 0):

Try FernFlower, it is a pretty cool decompile tool.
Uhmmmmm, I only get runtime error if i use FernFlower to decompile CLASS file but I get project error if I use JAD